# MatPlotLib graph output is an L along both X and Y axis. Can't figure out why

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I'm struggling with a matplotlib graph. I know it is probably something small but can't figure out what the issue is.

I have one pandas series of dates and another list that I have converted into a pandas dataframe (previously tried numpy array with the same result)

Here is my code below

```
datetime = load_profile['DateTime'].iloc[0:-1200]
ten_min_energy = pd.DataFrame(ten_min_energy)
print len(datetime)
print len(ten_min_energy)
print type(datetime)
print type(ten_min_energy)
print datetime.head(n=10)
print ten_min_energy.head(n=10)
plt.plot(datetime, ten_min_energy, linewidth=100.0)
plt.show()
```

The output

```
4183211
4183211
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>


   0   2013-03-03 14:01:46.500
   1   2013-03-03 14:01:47.000
   2   2013-03-03 14:01:47.500
   3   2013-03-03 14:01:48.000
   4   2013-03-03 14:01:48.500
   5   2013-03-03 14:01:49.000
   6   2013-03-03 14:01:49.500
   7   2013-03-03 14:01:50.000
   8   2013-03-03 14:01:50.500
   9   2013-03-03 14:01:51.000
   Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
                 0
   0  53173.123562
   1  53148.880560
   2  53124.978560
   3  53100.735558
   4  53076.492556
   5  53051.907555
   6  53028.005555
   7  53003.762553
   8  52979.860552
   9  52955.275551
```

Image is below. It you can't see. It is just a thick L line along the axes
[image: output]

Comment: You probably need to remove the ``linewidth=100.0`` specification.

Comment: I think my issue was the data. The linewidth was just to see where the line was because with it a 1 it was just blank. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Plot a histogram and see what the data distribution look like. The plot can tell you whether your data is what you expected.